# multiple subscribe in one cntoller not taking morethan 10

Tags: meteor

```
subscriptions: function() {   
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions1');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions2');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions3');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions4');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions5');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions6');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions7');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions8');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions9');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions10');
        subs.subscribe('subscriptions11');
         }
    }
```

If i remove last line subscribe from the above code its working fine.
How to do more than 10 subscribe in one controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think You should combine Your publications (return more than one), like:

```
Meteor.publish('test', function (_id) {
  check(_id, String);
  var testA = testA.find(_id);
  var testB = testB.find(_id);
  return [testA, testB];
});
```